# Why is join standalone, instead of part of the minimal implementation of the Monad typeclass?

Tags: haskell

I would prefer defining an instance of Monad via the join function instead of `>>=` ... Starting from that equivalence:

```
x >>= f = join (fmap f x)
```

Could you define a Monad instance only with join?

I would have expected join in Monad with: `{-# MINIMAL (>>=)| join #-}`

Why is `join` at the top level and not even in the `Monad` typeclass?

Comment: That `join` is a toplevel function, not a member of the typeclass above.

Comment: ho you are rigth because of the indent...

Comment: I have refined my question now thank you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sadly, `join` is not a part of the `Monad` typeclass in GHC’s standard library because of technical restrictions related to generalized newtype deriving and the roles system. Long story short, given some newtype `newtype T m a = MkT (m a)`, GHC is not smart enough to figure out how to prove representational equality between `m (m a)` and `m (T m a)`, which is necessary for proving representational equality for the first argument of `join` (which has type `m (m a) -> m a`).

Fortunately, a recent extension to GHC Haskell, `QuantifiedConstraints`, might make it possible to make the roles system smart enough to support this. For a more detailed treatment of both the problem and its potential solution, see Ryan Scott’s blog post, [How QuantifiedConstraints can let us put join back in Monad](https://ryanglscott.github.io/2018/03/04/how-quantifiedconstraints-can-let-us-put-join-back-in-monad/).

Comment: ok, do I risk anything by defining my own join function for the implementation of >>= for a given Monad instance ? is it a bad practice, from my current knowledge, I can't see how I could  be impacted by doing that...

Comment: @NicolasHenin Aside from being potentially less efficient, there isn’t really any downside for doing that, no.

Answer (score 7):

`join` is not in `Monad` because it would break `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` in a subtle way for newtype-wrapped monad transformers, a very common use case. See [the GHC wiki](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Roles2#join) for details.

Answer (score 0):

`join` isn't defined in the `Applicative` class. Check the indentation; all the class methods are indented, whereas `join` isn't. So it's not a class method.

Sadly, `join` isn't in the `Monad` class either, so there's no possibility of defining the class that way. `join` is defined identically for all monads.

Currently, the best you can do is define a `myCustomJoin` function, and then use that in the `Monad` instance definition of `>>=`.